# My tilde key doesn't work on Unreal Engine

Tags: keyboard, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, tilde, unreal-development-kit

I am new to unreal engine. My keyboard doesn't recognize the tilde(~) key. When I press once, nothing happens. When I press twice it prints two ~~ key. I am trying to open console command window, but nothing happens. Have you got any solution?

I tried to press tilde key to open console command view, but nothing happened.

Comment: Could you please specify where exactly your problem occurs? UDK is UE3.x and UE3, UE4 and UE5 are different tools. What keyboard do you use? What language do you have you set in your operating system? This question is rather vague and can't really be answered without more information.